# How to mock Jest Redis in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redis, jestjs, nestjs

I'm working on NestJs application and wrote unit test for my `authenticateUser` function in `user.service.ts`.It's has pass in my local machine.but when I deployed it in to server and run unit test, i got an error `Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED`.Seems like redis mock is not working.How should I mock redis and resolve this issue for working?

**user.service.ts**

```
async authenticateUser(authDto: AuthDTO): Promise<AuthResponse> {
    try {
     const userData = await this.userRepository.findOne({msisdn});
     if(userData){
         await this.redisCacheService.setCache(msisdn, userData);
     }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

**redisCache.service.ts**

```
export class RedisCacheService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache,
  ) {}

  async setCache(key, value) {
    await this.cache.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

**user.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('Test User Service', () => {
  let userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>;
  let userService: UserService;
  let redisCacheService: RedisCacheService;
  let cacheManager: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        UserEntity,
        RedisCacheService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(UserEntity),
          useClass: registeredApplicationRepositoryMockFactory,
        },
      ],
      imports: [CacheModule.register({})],
    }).compile();

    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    userRepository = module.get<Repository<UserEntity>>(
      getRepositoryToken(UserEntity),
    );
    redisCacheService = module.get<RedisCacheService>(RedisCacheService);
    cacheManager = module.get<any>(CACHE_MANAGER);
  });

  it('authenticateUser should return success response', async () => {
    const userEntity = { id: 1, name: 'abc', age: 25 };
    const mockSuccessResponse = new AuthResponse(
      HttpStatus.OK,
      STRING.SUCCESS,
      `${STRING.USER} ${STRING.AUTHENTICATE} ${STRING.SUCCESS}`,
      {},
    );

    jest.spyOn(userRepository, 'findOne').mockResolvedValueOnce(userEntity);
    jest.spyOn(redisCacheService, 'setCache').mockResolvedValueOnce(null);

    expect(await userService.authenticateUser(mockAuthBody)).toEqual(mockSuccessResponse);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your `RedisCacheService` is loading the `@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)` which subsequently tries to connect to Redis. You can fully mock `RedisCacheService` see https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks or https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Comment: is it because of `CACHE_MANAGER`? can i mock entire redis here?

Comment: You can use a [`npm redis-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-server) and create a Redis instance before creating the `TestingModule` (in `BeforEach`). this way a temporary Redis-Server will be created for each test (just add `AfterEach` to remove it). But... if you are looking to write Unit-Test you should mock the `RedisCacheService` instead of adding a network component to the mix.

Answer (score 9):

You can mock CACHE_MANAGER using a custom provider:

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

describe('AppService', () => {
  let service: AppService;
  let cache: Cache;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AppService,
        {
          provide: CACHE_MANAGER,
          useValue: {
            get: () => 'any value',
            set: () => jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    })
    .compile();

    service = app.get<AppService>(AppService);
    cache = app.get(CACHE_MANAGER);
  });

  // Then you can use jest.spyOn() to spy and mock

  it(`should cache the value`, async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(cache, 'set');

    await service.cacheSomething();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spy.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('key');
    expect(spy.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual('value');
  });

  it(`should get the value from cache`, async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(cache, 'get');

    await service.getSomething();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it(`should return the value from the cache`, async () => {
    jest.spyOn(cache, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce('value');
    
    const res = await service.getSomething();

    expect(res).toEqual('value');
  }),
});
```

More details on Custom Providers: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

Two more things, for unit testing you shouldn't import modules but mock the dependencies instead. And as Daniel said, UserService is not using CACHE_MANAGER but RedisCacheService, so you should mock RedisCacheService.

Usually the best thing to do is to only provide the service you're testing and mock the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that is very good way of mocking almost anything for testing

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I overrode the CACHE_MANAGER

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        const app = await Test.createTestingModule({
          providers: [
            AppService,
            {
              provide: CACHE_MANAGER,
              useValue: {
                get: () => 'any value',
                set: () => jest.fn(),
              },
            },
          ],
        }).overrideProvider(CACHE_MANAGER)
          .useValue({
              get: jest.fn(),
              set: jest:fn()
         }).compile();
    
        service = app.get<AppService>(AppService);
        cache = app.get(CACHE_MANAGER);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to use the jest spy functions you need to return the jest function directly.

```
    providers: [
        AppService,
        {
          provide: CACHE_MANAGER,
          useValue: {
            get: () => 'any value',
            set: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
```